# Can't aggregate data by date to calculate point path length

Tags: length, points-to-line, grouping, aggregate

I have a table with the coordinates of the movement of the car, its id and the time the coordinate point was received. When I try to calculate the mileage of a car by grouping points by day, an error occurs.

The table that I use:

```
CREATE TABLE geolocation (
    geo_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
    vehicle INT,
    latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    geom geometry(POINT, 4326),
    received_at TIMESTAMP
);
```

And here's the request I'm trying to make:

```
SELECT ROUND(ST_LengthSpheroid(ST_MakeLine(geom), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')::numeric, 2) as length
    FROM geolocation
    WHERE vehicle = 4 AND received_at BETWEEN '2023-03-01 12:00:00-00' AND '2023-03-15 23:59:59-00'
    GROUP BY date_trunc('DAY', received_at)
;
```

The error that my IDE highlights is this:

`Column 'geom' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

But the `st_MakeLine()` function is an aggregate function, what am I doing wrong?